# How to forward trace headers in responses with .Net 5 Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient, .net-5

Is there a reason why distributed trace headers are not sent back in responses?

Suppose a client makes a request like this:

```
private static readonly AssemblyName AssemblyName = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName();
private static readonly ActivitySource ActivitySource = new(AssemblyName.Name, AssemblyName.Version.ToString()); 
//...........................
ActivitySource.AddActivityListener(new ActivityListener
{
    ShouldListenTo = s => s.Name == AssemblyName.Name,
    SampleUsingParentId = (ref ActivityCreationOptions<string> activityOptions) => ActivitySamplingResult.AllData,
    Sample = (ref ActivityCreationOptions<ActivityContext> activityOptions) => ActivitySamplingResult.AllData,
});

using var _act = ActivitySource.StartActivity("TestAPI", ActivityKind.Client);
//...........................
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("...");
```

A request arrives to a controller with a header:

```
traceparent: 00-f0aba4f068a9394e99e11a2dd6d29ac0-fb081bd099309248-00
```

Is there a way to forward this header back to client in a response?
Something like:

```
traceparent: 00-f0aba4f068a9394e99e11a2dd6d29ac0-*response_span_id*-00
```

This is needed to correlate all request-responses in client's logs.

Or perhaps I'm misusing this feature and there is a better way?

Comment: Why can't you just add these directly to the response eg. in middleware? 
Something like: `context.Response.Headers["traceparent"] = "00-f0aba4f068a9394e99e11a2dd6d29ac0-*response_span_id*-00";`

Comment: I was thinking if there is something built-in for this. Or if not, what is the reason for that? May be what I'm after has some flaws?